# laravel return View::make in new tab

Tags: php, laravel

How can I return a `View::make` (from "route") to be displayed in a new tab using Laravel? I have tried to achieve this with the following code however it is not opening the view in a new tab:

```
return View::make('reports.cars')->with('cont', $u);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to modify controller code, just use [`target="_blank"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp):

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank">example.com</a>
```

> `_blank` opens the linked document in a new window or tab

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to to what you are asking from the server side. Tab controls are client side only and handled by the browser.

You can do for example:

```
<a href="{{ route('name') }} " target="_blank">Open in a new tab</a>
```